# How to add location to calendar-entry?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, calendar

Below you can find the code I'm using to add an entry to a users calendar.

I was wondering how to add a **location stamp** to the entry - and I found the `event.structuredLocation` property.

How can I add **(lat/lon) - coordinates** to the entry? Using `CLLocationCoordinate2D(lat:, lon:)` is not working.

```
func addReminder() {
    let eventStore : EKEventStore = EKEventStore()
    let event:EKEvent = EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore)
    event.title = "myevent"
    event.startDate = Date()
    event.endDate = Date()
    event.calendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents
    event.structuredLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 1.0, longitude: 2.0) // not working
    do {
        try eventStore.save(event, span: .thisEvent)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("error : \(error)")
    }
}
```

**Edit (1)** : I'm sure I have to use `EKStructuredLocation`. But I have no clue how to implement this either? (`EKStructuredLocation(mapItem: MKMapItem)`)

**Edit (2)**:

```
let map = MKMapItem()
map.name = "myplace"
map.placemark.coordinate.latitude = 10.0 // error
map.placemark.coordinate.longitude = 10.0 // error
```

**Edit (3)**:

Is it possible to add **bold text** to the event.notes property?

```
event.notes = "default text and bold text" // like html 
//"default text and <b>bold text</b>"
```

Any help would be very appreciated :)

Comment: I gave you an alternative to your edit 2, where you create your structured location using a CLLocation rather than an MKMapItem. As for your question about a note containing bold text, it appears that the answer is no. The notes property is a `String`, not an `AttributedString`, and I don't see any attributed string properties at all. Further, the calendar app doesn't appear to support styled text in the notes field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used it before, but if you look at the docs for `EKStructuredLocation`, it has an initializer that takes a title, and it has 3 properties:

```
var title: String? ///The title of the location.
var geoLocation: CLLocation? //The core location.
var radius: Double ///A minimum distance from the core location that would trigger the alarm or reminder.
```

So you'd use code like this:

```
var structuredLocation = EKStructuredLocation(title:"title") //Put your title here

let location = CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: long) //use your lat/long vals
structuredLocation.geoLocation = location

structuredLocation.radius = 1000 //This would be a 1 KM distance. Modify as desired

event.structuredLocation = structuredLocation
```